# OperationalError at /register/

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms-authentication, heroku-postgres

When I am trying to signup in django app on heroku, it's saying `no such table: auth_user` . I tried to run `manage.py migrate -syncdb`. It execute successfully but still the problem is same. I works perfectly in development environment.
What can be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `auth_user` model looks like, but I'm going to guess it has a `Meta` option of `managed = False`. Switching this to `managed = True` should resolve the issue. From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/), this ensures that Django will create the necessary tables on `migrate` commands.

If this is not the case, please provide the code where you defined your model and I'll try an alternate route.